# Why can't I access the Web Telegram website (error NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID)?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, security, browser

Whether I use Firefox or Chrome, I'm not able to access the https://web.telegram.org/ website. I get the following on Chrome:

> Your connection is not private Attackers might be trying to steal your
> information from web.telegram.org (for example, passwords, messages,
> or credit cards). Learn more NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID Subject:
> web.telegram.org
>
> - Issuer: Cisco Umbrella Secondary SubCA fra-SG
> - Expires on: Nov 27, 2023
> - Current date: Nov 25, 2023

And on Firefox:

> - Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead
> - Firefox detected a potential security threat and did not continue to web.telegram.org. If you visit this site, attackers could try to steal
>   information like your passwords, emails, or credit card details.
>
> What can you do about it?
>
> The issue is most likely with the web site, and there is nothing you
> can do to resolve it.
>
> If you are on a corporate network or using anti-virus software, you
> can reach out to the support teams for assistance. You can also notify
> the web site’s administrator about the problem.

I have fully updated (just completed update/upgrade, which I do every day or so) and restarted my PC. I've also noticed for that the last few days that I can't access https://rauias.com, https://www.amazon.in/, https://byjus.com/ and many more getting the same security warnings.

Comment: Try to uninstall Firefox or Chrome (save needed data such as bookmarks) and reinstall from the website.

Comment: @harrymc: Why would reinstalling the browser fix this?  Both of them have the same issue.

Comment: You are subject to a man-in-the-middle attack. If this is a corporate network, this may be legit, but ask your admin just in case. If this is a private internet connection… good luck.

Comment: Also check this [OpenDNS support article](https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/227987007) which could be related.

Comment: Disabling Cisco Umbrella would be the first necessary step, if you are not the network administrator for your corporation, then you should probably not disable it. Since the use of Cisco Umbrella is intentional you can ignore the warnings.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, a security product called "[Cisco Umbrella](https://umbrella.cisco.com/)" is tampering with your connection to these websites. As HTTPS has been built to prevent exactly that your browsers notice and alert you about it.

If you want this software and whoever deployed it to intercept all secure communication, install the certificate. The [link](https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/227987007) [DanielB](https://superuser.com/users/219095/daniel-b) provided seems to guide you through the process, although I can't confirm if it's legitimate.

In case you don't want this to happen, just don't install the certificate, stop using HTTP while you are in the network and contact its administrator. The only way to securely visit these websites is to do so via a VPN that isn't blocked, or by using another network altogether until the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

There likely is a packet inspection (DPI) going on and for that the Cisco device would have to be the TLS server for you as TLS client, but also be the TLS client for the actual server.
If DPI is intended, you must install that certificate to your trusted CAs.
If DPI is not intended here, you should tell this to your network admin who enabled this.